# In a three level business unit hierarchy, how does data sharing work?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sfmc-business-unit

In a Business Unit setup where we have three levels (Parent, Level 1 & Level 2), where BU1 will be the parent, BU2 will be a child of BU1 and BU3 will be a child of BU2; how does data sharing work for BU3?

I understand we have to put any DE's into the Shared Data Extensions, will BU3 have access to any Data Extensions placed by BU1 and BU2? or only its closest parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving to Shared Folder means "physically" moving to Parent / Enterprise level. That is the top level BU, in your Case BU1.

Data Extensions in Shared then become accessible through the ENT. prefix.
UI visibility (and only that) is controlled by the folder settings.

There is no equivalent of the ENT. prefix for BUs other than the top-level one, and the ENT prefix does not give any indication about the question from what BU the DE was put into Shared.

Essentially, "Shared" acts like a boolean.
Either a DE is on ENT. level or not, as it was "physically" moved.

This means:

will BU3 have access to any Data Extensions placed in Shared by BU1 and BU2?

Yes.

or only its closest parent?

No.

As a matter of fact, once you move something to Shared (ENT), SSJS, AMPScript and SQL have access to it from *all* BUs, regardless of the BU hierarchy.

So once shared (from anywhere), you can control visibility by BU in the folder Permissions in Email Studio, and access your DE (even if "invisible") from BU1 (obviously), BU2 (using ENT.), BU3 (using ENT.) and anywhere else through the above means.

I just retested it to the described effect using Query Studio.

- Create DE on level2
- Move to Shared Data Extensions, into a specific folder.
- In Parent, go to Email Studio, right click on that folder, only give access to BU3
- Go to BU3, try access via SQL using ENT.

```
SELECT test FROM ENT.testDE
```

= query runs successfully

- Go to another BU on Level3 (BU4), try access via SQL using ENT.

```
SELECT test FROM ENT.testDE
```

= query runs successfully

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is no dependency on how many levels of Business Units you have, it is going to be up to you which Business Unit will have permission and not.

By default, when a new Business Unit is created it would have an access to all Shared DEs.

You can follow this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_set_ent2_shared_de_permissions.htm&type=5) for Shared DEs and this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_share_folders_and_content.htm&type=5) for Shared Content.